# Get DateTime value From FieldInfo

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection, system.reflection, expressionvisitor

I am tryning to retrieve a `DateTime` via reflection. The value is not inside a class or a static class, but it is from a `lambda expression`...

I have this really simple lambda expression: `ATest => ATest.MyDate == DateTime.Now`

Now, via an `ExpressionVisitor` I am trying getting datetime value:

```
public class ExpressionComparionsVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public Expression Modify(Expression expression)
    {
        return base.Visit(expression);
    }


    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            if (node.Member.MemberType == System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Field)
            {
                if (node.Type ==  typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    System.Reflection.FieldInfo fieldInfo = node.Member as System.Reflection.FieldInfo;

                    if (fieldInfo != null)
                    {
                        //Here what I have tried, but no success

                        //var n = (DateTime)fieldInfo.GetValue(fieldInfo);
                        //var n = (DateTime)fieldInfo.GetValue(typeof(DateTime));
                        //var n = (DateTime)fieldInfo.GetValue(node.Member);
                        //var n = (DateTime)fieldInfo.GetValue(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

How can I get  the DateTime value of that field?
Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What value do you need?

Comment: I am tryng to convert a labda expression in a Azure.QueryTable

Comment: You are trying to convert it to what? It seems we have [XY  problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, so please add desired output/converted lambda.

Answer (score 0):

In short you can't. Your lambda `ATest => ATest.MyDate == DateTime.Now` represents a function that accepts a parameter (`ATest`) and returns boolean based on equality `ATest.MyDate` to `DateTime.Now`, so the value of `ATest.MyDate` can different for different provided inputs. To get some concrete value you need to provide some concrete input:

```
class MyClass {public DateTime MyDate;}

var someVal = new MyClass { MyDate = new DateTime(2020, 01, 01) };
Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> expr = ATest => ATest.MyDate == DateTime.Now;
var node = (expr.Body as BinaryExpression).Left as MemberExpression;
var fi = node.Member as FieldInfo;
Console.WriteLine(fi.GetValue(someVal)); // prints 1 January of 2020 in corresponding format
```

Comment: mm.. it seems like the only one difference is the date incapsulated a class. Right?

Comment: @Ciccio nope, a little bit more has changed)